# Where can I find examples from the Python source distribution, such as Modules/xxmodule.c?

Tags: python

I am reading in the Python documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#a-simple-example, Section 1.4, where it says:

> A more substantial example module is included in the Python source distribution as Modules/xxmodule.c. This file may be used as a template or simply read as an example.

How do I figure out where Modules/xxmodule.c is located? Is this something that gets saved when I install Python?

I'm using Python 3.7 32bit on Windows.

Comment: The `xxmodule.c` can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/xxmodule.c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C files aren't included when you install Python. They're included in [source code distributions](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/), or you can find them in the [CPython Git repository](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Modules).